# powershell foreach-object with if statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, hashtable, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run this script that basically reads/interprets text in from a textfile and stores the "key" and "value" into a hashtable. Now I want to change a specific key and value as I am reading the text from the text file.

The following is the text in my file:

```
line1 = apple  
line2 = firetruck  
line3 = cricket  
line4 = gorilla  
line5 = elephant  
line6 = banana  
line7 = jumper  
line8 = hat  
line9 = deer  
line10 = igloo
```

Here is my code:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,  HelpMessage="Please specify the text filename.")]$fileName
)


$hashTable = @{}
$textFile = Get-Content $filename | ForEach-Object `
{
    $equalindex = $_.IndexOf("=")
    $key = $_.Substring(0,$equalindex)

    if($key -like "line2")
    {
        $key = "line2 has been changed"
    }

    $remainingLen = (($_.Length - 1) -$equalindex)
    $value = $_.Substring($equalindex +1, $remainingLen)

    if($value -like "value2")
    {
        $value = "value2 has been changed"
    }

    $hashtable.Add($key,$value)
} 

$hashtable.Set_Item("line5","line5 value has been changed")
$hashtable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object name
```

When I run my code it outputs the hashtable but does not change my "line2" key or my "value2" value. Is this the correct/most logical way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove leading and (or) trailing spaces. Try this:

```
$ht=@{}

Get-Content $filename | foreach{

    $key,$value = $_.Split('=') | foreach {$_.Trim()}

    if($key -like "line2")
    {
       $key = "line2 has been changed"
    }

    if($value -like "value2")
    {
        $value = "value2 has been changed"
    }

    $ht.Add($key,$value)
}

$ht.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object name


Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
line1                          apple                                                                                                                                     
line10                         igloo                                                                                                                                     
line2 has been changed         firetruck                                                                                                                                 
line3                          cricket                                                                                                                                   
line4                          gorilla                                                                                                                                   
line5                          elephant                                                                                                                                  
line6                          banana                                                                                                                                    
line7                          jumper                                                                                                                                    
line8                          hat                                                                                                                                       
line9                          deer
```

Comment: @ray023 I'm sorry guys I included those spaces when I was posting the text so it would add a line break but then forgot to take it out when the site told me it wasn't formatted right. (I needed to add the "code" indent to my text file text). So the text in my textfile doesn't have any trailing spaces. I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: ahh sorry Shay and @ray023 I saw what you were saying I just implemented the code and it worked thank you. I will have to read up on the Split command a little more. i also just realized I was searching for text "value2" instead of "firetruck" which was the actual value for line 2 which is why that value wasnt't changing. Thanks for your quick responses I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I think the trailing space throwing you off.

Change this:

```
$key = $_.Substring(0,$equalindex)
```

to this:

```
$key = $_.Substring(0,$equalindex).Trim(' ')
```

or maybe the index is off as this seems to work too:

```
$key = $_.Substring(0,$equalindex - 1)
```